# Sending html contact form to email using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, nodemailer

Hi i'm trying to take the data of my form and submit it to my email (mostafamasri@outlook.com) i want to receive the email of the sender from the input and his name, and the message in an organized way.

this is my html code :

```
  <div id="contact" class="contact">
<h5 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif; font-size: 47px; color:#fff;  padding-top: 110px">Get in touch</h5><br>


<form method="POST" id="contact-form" action="send">
  <p>Dear Mostafa,</p>
  <p>My
    <label for="your-name">name</label> is
    <input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" minlength="3" placeholder="(your name here)" required> and</p>

  <p>my
    <label for="email">email address</label> is
    <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
  </p>

  <p> I have a
    <label  for="your-message">message</label> for you,</p>

  <p>
    <textarea name="your-message" id="your-message" placeholder="(your msg here)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send!">
  <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
  </svg>
  <small>Submit</small>
</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

This is my nodejs code :

`var express = require('express');`
`var bodyParser = require("body-parser");`
`var app = express();`
`var path = require("path");`

`'use strict';`
`const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');`

`var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;`

`nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {`

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'mostafamasri@outlook.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'mamxais'  // generated ethereal password
    }
});

// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender@server.com', // sender address
    to: 'sql.leb@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@blurdybloop.com>
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
});});
```

any help or guidance would be appreciated guys thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

1. Make the html as single line string(copy and paste the html code in any browser's address bar. Select all(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), copy and paste the single line content in a text editor-notepad).
2. Escape double quotes (replace all **"** with **\"**)
3. Copy the formatted html string, assign to a variable and use in nodemailer request

var htmlContent = "formatted html string";